# AFNetworking download loop loses authentication

Tags: ios, ipad, afnetworking, connectivity, download

So I'm in a situation where I have do download multiple video files in an iOS app before going to the main screen and I'm using AFNetworking 2 for it. If I have to download one file everything is fine, but when I have to download multiple files some fail with this error, it isn't always the same files, it seems to be random.. :

Error : Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7ff943f4fcb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=

Say I'm using this code :

```
MainView *mainViewController = [[MainView alloc] init];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:AUTH_USERNAME2 password:AUTH_PASSWORD2 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:self.topVideoPath];


__block int countVideos = 0;
__block int totalvideos = [videoItems count];
for (int i = 0; i < [videoItems count]; i++){

   NSLog(@"dict array : %@" , self.dictArray);
   NSMutableDictionary *itemDict = [self.dictArray objectAtIndex:i];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[itemDict objectForKey:@"video"]];
   NSString *videoString = [itemDict objectForKey:@"video"];
   NSString *specificPath = [[fileManager currentDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.dat", [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"]]];
   TopItem *item = [videoItems objectAtIndex:i];

            if (![videoString isEqualToString:@""]) {

                [fileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:self.topVideoPath];

                NSString *moviePath = [[fileManager currentDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Movie%@.mp4", [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"]]];
                NSString *correctMoviePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KyoskSkeleton/TopVideo/Movie%@.mp4", [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"]];

                AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
                [operation setCredential:credential];
                operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:moviePath append:NO];
                [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

                    float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
                    NSLog(@"The downloading progress : %f", progress);


                }];
                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                    countVideos = countVideos + 1;

                    NSLog(@"specific path : %@", specificPath);
                   [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:item toFile:specificPath];

                    if (countVideos == totalvideos ){
                    mainViewController.topScrollViewContent = self.topScrollViewContent;  
                        if ([self.responseDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pushController:)]) {
                            [self.responseDelegate performSelector:@selector(pushController:) withObject:mainViewController];
                        }
                    }
                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Not Downloaded");
                    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);

                    countVideos = countVideos + 1;
                }];

                [operation start];
}
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed it with an NSOperationque with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3, so only 3 video's are downloaded at the same time. Probably the server had problems with the long and many connections.